# Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized

Tags: java, android, appium, adb

I am getting following error when trying to launch the application in simulator:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.6.1
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
FAILED: mobile.tutorial.Exercise.AppiumTest
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
System info: host: 'Pranjals-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14f7:9f61:777f:238c%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.5', java.version: '11.0.15.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:app=//Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk, appium:deviceName=Nexus 5 API R, platformName=ANDROID}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {app: //Users//pranjal//eclipse-w..., deviceName: Nexus 5 API R, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:146)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:224)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:79)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:116)
    at mobile.tutorial.Exercise.AppiumTest(Exercise.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:962)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

I have tried using DesiredCapabilities and UiAutomator2Options but I get the same error.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "//Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus 5 API R");   
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

UiAutomator2Options

```
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setDeviceName("Nexus 5 API R");
        options.setApp("//Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk");
        
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),options);
```

Selenium Appium logs:

```
HHTTP] Waiting until the server is closed
[HTTP] Received server close event
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true
[Appium]   allowInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium]   denyInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] Request idempotency key: 8c85cfdf-b326-4ae6-9e79-de067f5f8e59
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"//Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk","appium:deviceName":"Nexus 5 API R","platformName":"android"}}}
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"//Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk","appium:deviceName":"Nexus 5 API R","platformName":"android"}}]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1661132203235 (20:36:43 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[Appium] 
[Appium] ======================================================================
[Appium]   DEPRECATION WARNING:
[Appium] 
[Appium]   The 'automationName' capability was not provided in the desired 
[Appium]   capabilities for this Android session
[Appium] 
[Appium]   Setting 'automationName=UiAutomator2' by default and using the 
[Appium]   UiAutomator2 Driver
[Appium] 
[Appium]   The next major version of Appium (2.x) will **require** the 
[Appium]   'automationName' capability to be set for all sessions on all 
[Appium]   platforms
[Appium] 
[Appium]   In previous versions (Appium <= 1.13.x), the default was 
[Appium]   'automationName=UiAutomator1'
[Appium] 
[Appium]   If you wish to use that automation instead of UiAutomator2, please 
[Appium]   add 'automationName=UiAutomator1' to your desired capabilities
[Appium] 
[Appium]   For more information about drivers, please visit 
[Appium]   http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/intro/ and explore the 
[Appium]   'Drivers' menu
[Appium] 
[Appium] ======================================================================
[Appium] 
[Appium] Appium v1.22.3 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.70.1) session
[Appium] Applying relaxed security to 'AndroidUiautomator2Driver' as per server command line argument. All insecure features will be enabled unless explicitly disabled by --deny-insecure
[BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:app": "//Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "Nexus 5 API R"
[BaseDriver]   },
[BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[BaseDriver]     {}
[BaseDriver]   ]
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 73660627-8680-4052-982b-1642dc26b1bf
[BaseDriver] Using local app '//Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Checking whether app is actually present
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 start-server'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[ADB] Getting connected devices
[ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"emulator-5554","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Using device: emulator-5554
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 start-server'
[ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 29
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 10
[ADB] Device API level: 29
[UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy 1''
[AndroidDriver] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
[ADB] Package name: 'io.appium.android.apis'
[ADB] Main activity name: 'io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos'
[AndroidDriver] Parsed package and activity are: io.appium.android.apis/io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device'
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell echo ping'
[AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('3.4.0' >= '3.4.0')
[ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade '/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/io.appium.settings/apks/settings_apk-debug.apk'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)io\.appium\.settings\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[Logcat] Starting logs capture with command: /Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 logcat -v threadtime
[UiAutomator2] Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to local port 8200
[ADB] Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:8200 tcp:6790'
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is greater or equal to the application version name ('4.27.0' >= '4.27.0')
[UiAutomator2] io.appium.uiautomator2.server installation state: sameVersionInstalled
[ADB] Checking app cert for /Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk
[ADB] Using the previously cached signature entry for 'appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'
[ADB] sha256 hash did match for 'appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed
[ADB] Checking app cert for /Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk
[ADB] Using the previously cached signature entry for 'appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[ADB] sha256 hash did match for 'appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Server packages are not going to be (re)installed
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for services to be available
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list instrumentation'
[UiAutomator2] Instrumentation target 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' is available
[ADB] Adding packages ["io.appium.settings","io.appium.uiautomator2.server","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test"] to Doze whitelist
[ADB] Got the following command chunks to execute: [["dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.settings",";","dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.uiautomator2.server",";","dumpsys","deviceidle","whitelist","+io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test",";"]]
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.settings ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.uiautomator2.server ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test ;'
[ADB] Checking app cert for //Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk
[ADB] Using the previously cached signature entry for 'ApiDemos-debug.apk'
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.android.apis
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.android.apis'
[ADB] 'io.appium.android.apis' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.android.apis'
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.android.apis'
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.android.apis' is greater or equal to the application version name ('4.0.0' >= '4.0.0')
[ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade '//Users//pranjal//eclipse-workspace//MobileAutomationLearning//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk'
[AndroidDriver] Performing fast reset on 'io.appium.android.apis'
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.android.apis
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys package io.appium.android.apis'
[ADB] 'io.appium.android.apis' is installed
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.android.apis'
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm clear io.appium.android.apis'
[AndroidDriver] Performed fast reset on the installed 'io.appium.android.apis' application (stop and clear)
[UiAutomator2] Performing shallow cleanup of automation leftovers
[UiAutomator2] No obsolete sessions have been detected (socket hang up)
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[UiAutomator2] Starting UIAutomator2 server 4.27.0
[UiAutomator2] Using UIAutomator2 server from '/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk' and test from '/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","instrument","-w","-e","disableAnalytics",true,"io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] socket hang up
[Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
[Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
[Instrumentation] The process has exited with code 0
[UiAutomator2] The instrumentation process has been unexpectedly terminated. Retrying UiAutomator2 startup (#1 of 1)
[UiAutomator2] Performing strict cleanup of automation leftovers
[UiAutomator2] No obsolete sessions have been detected (socket hang up)
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'uiautomator' processes
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep -f \(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\^\)uiautomator\(\[\[:blank:\]\]\|\$\)'
[ADB] No 'uiautomator' process has been found
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","instrument","-w","-e","disableAnalytics",true,"io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] socket hang up
[Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
[Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
[Instrumentation] The process has exited with code 0
[UiAutomator2] The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[UiAutomator2] Did not get confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'DELETE /' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.android.apis'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp:8200'
[UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[ADB] Running '/Users/pranjal/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy''
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1661132209667 (20:36:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
[W3C]     at Object.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:94:35)
[W3C]     at UiAutomator2Server.startSession (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/lib/uiautomator2.js:247:13)
[W3C]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.startUiAutomator2Session (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/lib/driver.js:416:5)
[W3C]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.createSession (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/lib/driver.js:229:7)
[W3C]     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:387:35)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 6434 ms - 859
[HTTP]
```

The simulator is running but the application is not deployed and installed. I tried solutions where people was asking to check Android sdk/tools and but all is up to date and saved in the bash profile.

In the appium logs you can see the session is created.

Anyone has an idea what wrong i am doing?